# python BeautifulSoup table scraping after search

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull data from a web table after performing a search/filter from a website. I'm having issues wrapping my head around how to perform the search then scrape. Below I've added the HTML from the request form as well as the code I have so far. I've tried multiple methods but all unsuccessful. Ultimately I'd like to pull the data from the results table into a .csv.

```
<table title="Search Results" id="searchResults" class="defaultGrid" summary="Search results based on search criteria"
```

.

```
<a href="#" id="docSearchButton">Search</a>
```

.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import urllib
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd

    #here is where I wrote the search automation; Need to figure out how to combine above
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("httph:")

driver.maximize_window()

#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="districtDROPDOWN"]").send_keys(01)
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='districtDROPDOWN']")
select = Select(dropdown)
select.select_by_value("01")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='docSearchButton']").click()
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
#scraper starts here
finally:
#finally I have no clue what to do here; StackOverflow it is
```

Comment: it use XHR/JavaScript to get results as JSON from url [https://rrcsearch3.neubus.com/esd3-rrc/api.php?function=GetControls&json={"Neusearch":{"profile":"15","api_key":"publicuser","api_sig":"68461babf138014f252e64732ef3b1a0","targetProfileID":"15"}}&_=1512945838594](https://rrcsearch3.neubus.com/esd3-rrc/api.php?function=GetControls&json={"Neusearch":{"profile":"15","api_key":"publicuser","api_sig":"68461babf138014f252e64732ef3b1a0","targetProfileID":"15"}}&_=1512945838594)